# What can dialectology contribute to psycho- or neurolinguistics - or the other way around?

Tags: psycholinguistics, dialects, neurolinguistics

Dialectology is the study of geographical varieties of a language. The study of (for example) older dialects of English (such as the dialect spoken in the Northeast of England around Newcastle) and more recent dialects (such as Indian or Australian English) can contribute a lot to other areas of linguistics. For example, the authors of "[The Dialect Laboratory.](http://benjamins.com/#catalog/books/slcs.128/main) Dialects as a testing ground for theories of language change" argue that dialectology can contribute in many ways to the study of language change.

**Q:** Does dialectology also have something to contribute [psycho-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psycholinguistics) or [neurolinguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurolinguistic) (the study of the cognitive and neural mechanisms underpinning the ability to use language)? Or the other way around? Are there any studies relying on this connection?

Comment: I think aspects such as *code switching* definitely cross the bounds of both dialectology and psycho-/neuro-linguistics for one example. We're interested in how/why/when people switch between a standard variety and a nonstandard variety or dialect of the same language.